# How to get user group in nodejs using passport-azure-ad

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

i am using nodejs passport-azure-ad for AD authentication with OIDCStrategy. Every thing is working fine but i am not able to fetch correct groups. Although i update `responseType: 'code id_token',` and getting groups id as well but groups are different from the azure portal showing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your scenario . If you wan to get group claims by setting `groupMembershipClaims` property in manifest . Your choices for setting the groupMembershipClaims property are null (the default), All or SecurityGroup. If you choose SecurityGroup you will get group claims in the JWT token for just security groups the user is a member of. If you choose All you will get group claims in the JWT token for security groups and distribution lists the user is a member of. If you want to just get security groups the user is a member of , you should set value to `SecurityGroup` , then you will find group object IDs now provided in the claims . You could check that value with object id value in group property from azure portal .

If your question is getting group name with group object id in token claims , please provide more details about that, for example , which api you are using .

If i misunderstand your scenario , please feel free to let me know .